# Excessive punctuation in modern Russian

Tags: пунктуация

I'm native Russian speaker who left the motherland for good about 15 years ago. I'm slowly losing the feel of the language and oftentimes can't determine whether what I see is a mistake or not. For example, in the quote below, is comma before the first 'ни' correct?

> Каждому из нас природой бесплатно дается некоторое количество дури, которой можно пользоваться, но которую нельзя, ни продать, ни скурить

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Your feeling of the language seems OK. The impact of a huge corpus of ungrammatical Russian of nowadays is a common problem, I believe.

Comment: Пользуясь случаем рекламирую сайт на этой же платформе для тех, кому русский - родной: [Русский язык](http://rus.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you don't need a comma before the first *ни*.